# localhost/drupal/drupal/mysite to localhost/mysite or mysite.com?

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, xampp

How do I change from localhost/htdocs/drupal-vn/drupal-vn/mysite1; ...mysite2 to www.mysite1.com and www.mysite2.com and to localhost/mysite?  Don't I use httpd.conf or something?  I'm on XP with XAMPP.

Also, what is this process called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some sites offering confusing tutorials on how to make this happen:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

Changes are to be made in apache configuration.
Please follow instruction here - good article if you follow step by step - http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412